# auto encoder with MFCC audio features

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, autoencoder, mfcc

I tried to train an auto encoder to learn feature representations from some segments of audio MFCC features(my dataset is TIMIT). So I used a fixed size window to cut the audio MFCC data(13 dimensional MFCC), My data is (None, window_size*13),here my window size is 20(frames). I trained a auto encoder with feed_forward type, use loss function as least squared error(the difference norm between prediction and label), the problem is my loss stops decrease at a high level. My network part code is here:

```
self.centers_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,self.train_centers[0].shape[1]],name = 'center_placeholder')



        layer = tf.layers.dense(self.centers_placeholder,2000,activation=tf.nn.relu)
        layer = tf.layers.batch_normalization(layer)

        layer = tf.layers.dense(layer,1500,activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
        layer = tf.layers.batch_normalization(layer)


        layer = tf.layers.dense(layer,500,activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
        layer = tf.layers.batch_normalization(layer)

        layer = tf.layers.dense(layer,100,activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
        layer = tf.layers.batch_normalization(layer)

        self.embedding= tf.layers.dense(layer,50,activation = tf.nn.leaky_relu)

        layer = tf.layers.dense(layer,100,activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
        layer = tf.layers.batch_normalization(layer)

        layer = tf.layers.dense(layer,500,activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
        layer = tf.layers.batch_normalization(layer)

        layer = tf.layers.dense(layer,1500,activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
        layer = tf.layers.batch_normalization(layer)


        layer = tf.layers.dense(layer,2000,activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
        layer = tf.layers.batch_normalization(layer)

        self.decoded = tf.layers.dense(layer,self.train_centers[0].shape[1],activation=None)

        #cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.sqrt(tf.square(neighbors_placeholder-decoder4)))
        self.cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.norm(self.centers_placeholder-self.decoded,ord=2,axis=1))
        #self.cost=tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=self.centers_placeholder,predictions=self.decoded))
        target_norm = tf.norm(self.centers_placeholder,ord=2,axis=1)
        difference_norm=tf.norm(self.centers_placeholder-self.decoded,ord=2,axis=1)
        self.metric = tf.reduce_mean(difference_norm/target_norm)
        print('model graph has built',flush=True)

        global_step=tf.Variable(0,trainable=False)
        starter_learning_rate=self.learning_rate
        lr=tf.train.exponential_decay(starter_learning_rate,global_step,100000,0.96,staircase=True)
        self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(self.cost,global_step=global_step)
        self.saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

I tried different architecture, deep or shallow, but it always convergence at a high level. Here is one example of my losses[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmMvx.png)

Can anyone help? Is there anyone has some experiments with MFCC in auto encoder?
Thanks!